# URL rewriting and url parameter

Tags: php, mysql, video, url-rewriting

I've been building my website from the very beginning until today with no framework or WYSIWYG software. I now realize that the way I made it could have been a lot simplier.

I'm a noob in php and mysql and wish to understand how it works. That's why I decided to make a website about a particular theme. That's the best practice to learn these 2 languages...

So,

My website goes about video content with daily updates.

I use to make per video a unique webpage... Now I've more than 300 pages of video content and I want to bring all this content into my database and put it all in one template webpage.

When I want to apply a change, I have to open all those webpages and make on each page the needed changes. Fortunatelly, the search en replace box helps me.

I just wanted to do something on the website that could make my routine and work a lot faster and easier.

I'd like to do some url rewriting with mysql requests.

I'm working on a piece of code, but I can't find what goes wrong with that.
Dreamweaver tells me that there's no error on the synthax, but when I preview it (WAMP) , it keeps showing me an error until a get rid of the 'p' paramater. Hereunder, I join you the code i'm using.

```
    <?php
include "connect.php";
$id = $_GET["id"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1"; //mysql tells me there's a error near LIMIT 1
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error()." ERROR");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

if($data["url"]!=$_GET["url"])
{
    header("location:/video/atest.php/".$data["id"]."-".$data["url"]); //if the URL is altered, it will be immediatelly fixed thanks to this function
}
?>
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1 ERROR

Thanks to that I will be able to insert on my database every piece of content for each unique video > title, description, ... without the need to make a thousand of changes and upload new webpages.

the URL parameters are also on my database and the php scripts makes the call to the database to retrieve the URL and make this look like a unique webpage.

Oh and sorry for my English...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Damn, I forgot to say you Hello for my first post.

Comment: You should never use a request parameter directly in an SQL query. Always escape the paramters using `mysql_real_escape_string` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL injection. Old `mysql` extension is deprecated, use `mysqli`. Better still use PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: @AyeshK - There is no header injection problem, since `$data` is fetched from database.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you answer. 
The problem remains the same.

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\video\atest.php on line 4

Other suggestions?

Comment: What you were getting before was a MySQL error. What you posted in your comment above is just a PHP notice. You can avoid it by checking if the index exist before using it `$id = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET["id"] : '');`. I am not sure what you are trying to do here. You refer to a parameter `p` which fixes the problem you are having, but I don't see any parameter / variable `p` in your code.

Comment: @RicardoBaglio -  Did you try using the `isset` function?

Comment: Hi,

I now have no problems when i'm using this.

<?php
require("connect.php");

$id = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET["id"] : ''); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error(). " ERROR");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

?>

What expect to do now is to retrieve the ID from my database and according to the id, the specifical content of each video on the DB will be released on my videopage template.

for example = 1-this-is-the-title-of-my-video-content
1 refers to the ID on the DB, the other content are the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

try echo $_GET["id"]; before sql and check if you are getting any value. And also learn "PDO" it is better than using direct sql statements or as Joyce said use escape_string.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you answer. I think I'll have to make some changes on my initial code if I want to use PDO right?

Answer (score 0):

Change your line:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";

TO THIS:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1";

Your SELECT is selecting the string '$id' rather than the php variable $id.